# Datastax Agent (Cassandra) Opscenter shutdown issue

Tags: datastax, opscenter

**after the datastax-agent is up  he is shutdown immediate?**
i'm getting that in log
(DataStax agent ran out of memory! Shutting down!
)

Comment: Which version of the datastax-agent are you using?  Also, how much free and overall memory is available on this system?

Comment: datastax-agent (6.0.2)

Comment: total memory in every node 64 G free 4G; MAX_HEAP_SIZE = 16 HEAP_NEWSIZE=4G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/datastax-agent/datastax-agent-env.sh` on the node and change the maxinmum RAM.
By default it is 128MB, but 256MB solved a similar problem for me. (`-Xmx256M`). Note: that's the file path for Debian.